How to set line_shape in Plotly.Blazor?
I'm trying to figure out how to create spline graphs using the Plotly.Blazor NuGet package, but I can't find anything like line_shape from the python version in the Plotly.Blazor github. Is there a way to do it, or do I need to find a different solution?
I'm currently using Scatter objects to plot my lines. Originally, I thought it would be something similar to how it is done in python:
line = Scatter(line_shape = "spline",)

So far, however, no such luck.

I think you are looking for syntax like below:
@using Plotly.Blazor.Traces.ScatterLib.LineLib
...
    IList<ITrace> data = new List<ITrace>
    {
        new Scatter
        {
            ... 
            Line= new Line {
                Color="red",
                Shape=ShapeEnum.Spline,
                Smoothing=1
            }
        }
    };
``

